# Robocopy folder and subfolders and files WITHOUT permissions , only datas

Tags: robocopy

I'm currently doing a file server migration using Robocopy.

I used the following commands to copy the folder to new server WITHOUT security permissions.

I want to copy only folder & files / subdirectories.

When attempting to open folder on destination file server then it says "Unable to display current owner."

is it normal ?

NEW FILE SERVER :

[image]

```
ROBOCOPY "driveletter:\source\file directory\" "driveletter:\destination\file directory\" /xf "pagefile.sys" "thumbs.db" "*.tmp" /xd "DfsrPrivate" "recycler" "$RECYCLE.BIN" "System Volume Information" /MIR /ZB /MT:16 /R:1 /W:1 /NP /TEE /LOG:"C:\tmp\LogName.log"
```